# How to make Oblique lines with CSS / Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I make a page like this with slanted lines?

[image]

Can I put an angle of 20 degrees for example? I have to put 3 div?

For now I put a first div to put a logo in the middle, then I put the navigation bar and I would like the navigation bar to be aligned with the angle just above the oblique line.
I have to work on bootstrap 3
I'm a bit lost. thank you very much for your help and explanations

```
<div class="container" style="background-color: #04342E; width:100%">
            <img class="img-responsive center-block" style="height: 600px; align-items: center;"; src="/i/gp-logo.png" />
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="justify-content: space-between; background-color: transparent; background: transparent; border-color: transparent;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="text-decoration: none">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link active" href="#" style="color: white;">Accueil</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: white;">Tableaux</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: white;">Papeterie</a>
                    </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: white;">Book</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: white;">A propos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: white;">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div>   
        </div> 
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can create div with `clip-path` I would recommand to use: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Either you use background with linear-gradient.

### DEMO with clip-path:

```css
body{
  background: #04342E;
  margin:0;
}
div.polygon{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: white;
  clip-path: polygon(0 25%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 75%);
  
  display:flex;
}

.content{
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.3); /** Just used to show the written area But it should be removed **/
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="polygon">
  <div class="content">
   Lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This way, can I add content in the white part?

Comment: @Kimako Yes you can, I edited my snippet to show you where you will be able to write  (in red strip) just remove the background-color. Yes you can

Comment: You roooooock ! Thanks a lot, really.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
  background-color: #04342E;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.container::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border-bottom: solid white 500px;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transform: skew(1000deg);
}

.container #content {
  background-color: #04342E;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

.container #content::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border-top: solid white 500px;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: skew(-1000deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="img-responsive center-block" style="height: 100px; align-items: center;" ; src="./images/image 5.png" />
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="justify-content: space-between; background-color: transparent; background: transparent; border-color: transparent;">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="text-decoration: none">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#" style="color: white;">Accueil</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: white;">Tableaux</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: white;">Papeterie</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: white;">Book</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: white;">A propos</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: white;">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
you can use psuedo classes in css to create this. see above for the code.
```

Comment: It's also working, thank you a lot for your time.  is it possible to make menu names follow the slant line? (just above)